# Raycasting Unity3d 3rd person shooter shooting out wrong

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make the enemy follow my player if they're close to him. 
I have made them follow my player if he's in front of them directly but this is not what I want. I want them to raycast his position or some way to make them follow him when they're so close.

This is the bit I need help with. It's attached to the enemy prefab that gets instantiated.

```
 var playerray : RaycastHit;
 var fwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3(Player.transform.position.x,Player.transform.position.y,Player.transform.position.z));
 if (Physics.Raycast(myTransform.position,fwd, playerray, DetectionDist)){
     Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, fwd, Color.red);
 }
```

[image]

[image]

Basically the direction is off for some reason and I can't figure out why.

Here's the full script just in case.

```
#pragma strict

var Speed : float = 8000;
var RayDist : float = 100;
var speed : float = 100;
var Player : Transform;
var attackPoint : Transform;
var Bullet : GameObject;
var myTransform : Transform;
var attackbase: boolean;
var spotted :boolean;
var DetectionDist : int = 100;

function Start(){
    myTransform = transform;
    Player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    attackPoint = GameObject.Find("attackPoint").transform;
}

function Update () {
    var hit: RaycastHit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.forward, hit, RayDist)){
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position,Vector3.forward, Color.green);

        if(hit.collider.tag == "Player")
        {
            spotted = true;
        }
    }
    if(spotted == true){
        var F = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3(Player.position.x, myTransform.position.y, Player.position.z) - myTransform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, F, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    if(spotted == false){
        var A = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3(attackPoint.position.x, myTransform.position.y, attackPoint.position.z) - myTransform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, A, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
//////////////////////ENEMY TO PLAYER RAY////////////////////////////////////////
    var playerray : RaycastHit;
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3(Player.transform.position.x,Player.transform.position.y,Player.transform.position.z));
    if (Physics.Raycast(myTransform.position,fwd, playerray, DetectionDist)){
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, fwd, Color.red);
    }
}
function OnCollisionEnter(coll : Collision){
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Pbullet"){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Player"){
        ///attack and make Player flash red.
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you expect someone to go through that much trouble to see you screen shots? Just upload it here.

Comment: sorry m8 im not lv 10 this site has a few pros and cons.

Comment: help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fwd = (Player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
```

This code fixed my error. It is now a perfect ray.

Comment: You should definitely not be raycasting every frame for this. If distance is all that matters and you already have access to the player's position, why don't you just test whether (Player.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude is less than the detection range? If it important this detection to be blocked by obstacles you can raycast afterward, but casting every frame will get very slow.

Comment: hello friend could you please give me an example ? or rewrite my bit of code so it check the transform positions between the two objects